# Question not answered.. who got the bounty now?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, bounty

I answered a question on Sharepoint.Stackexchange and got no replies. When the Bounty grace period ended, there was no good answer, no answer with 2 upvotes, and no answer that helped me at all. As in the FAQ:

> "If there's no answer meeting that criteria, the bounty is not awarded
>   to anyone."

That means it is gone? Should'nt i get it back to maybe restart that bounty with greater amount of rep to get an answer?

My Question:
[Hosting Office Templates in a Document Library (Office & SharePoint 2010)](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/51066/hosting-office-templates-in-a-document-library-office-sharepoint-2010)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aye, unfortunately the bounty points are gone at that point. However, the points preclude two items; more views, and more posting.

If your question is too open-ended or doesn't have enough detail, then you may not get the answer you are seeking. However, If you are actively updating your post, with new items you've tried -- and specifying more detail, the resolution provided by the users interacting with your posts will be amorphous and tailor their comments towards something closer to what you are looking for.

That said, with the addition of the views and posts, the reward of your points is a great incentive to get more attention.

Best of luck on your question, to get the resolution you are seeking.

Answer (score 4):

Yep your bounty is gone. I had this happen to me as well. Unfortunately, there isn't much you can do except try to break your question down or accept there might not be a good answer.

> **What happens if there's no answer after the bounty period?**
>
> If after the end of the bounty period a question has no answers, no
>   bounty will be awarded and the question will no longer be featured.
>
> Bounties are best understood as exchanging reputation for higher
>   question visibility and increased answerer motivation. A bounty does
>   not guarantee a response and is not refunded if none are received.

Source: [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Comment: Would be great though if the bounty was refunded. It's a waste of well earned points and might be a set back.